# Download excel file on Client side using Webservice and jQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, excel, web-services

I want to export data in excel in server side and download that excel file to client side on button click . I created a web service method and made an ajax call from jQuery. In the webservice, i was able to create excel and store it to the server side module but i am unable to download the file on client side. I've no idea how to do it? can any one help me? how to do it. 
I've attached  code what i've done.

//webservice code

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string ExportReport(int SelectedValue, string KeyValue, string DdlCltVal, string DdlLocVal, string DdlstfVal, int BtnID, DateTime StrDate, DateTime EndDate, int currentPage)
    {
        try
        {
            CommonFunction obj = new CommonFunction();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string rhead = "";
            if (SelectedValue != 0 && KeyValue == "0" && DdlCltVal == "0" && DdlLocVal == "0" && DdlstfVal == "0")
            {
                CourierReportController objCtr = new CourierReportController();
                dt = ListToDataTable.ToDataTable(objCtr.GetDailyReport(0, 10, SelectedValue));
                rhead = "Daily";
            }
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                sb.Append(column.ColumnName + "\t");
            }
            sb.Append("\n");
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    sb.Append(row[i].ToString() + "\t");
                }
                sb.Append("\n");
            }
            string strFilename = "CourierReport_" + rhead + ".xls";
            string strUploadPath = Server.MapPath("userexports").ToString();
            File.WriteAllText(strUploadPath + "\\" + strFilename, sb.ToString());
            return strFilename;         
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

//client side code

```
$('#btnExport').click(function (e) {
 var data= JSON2.stringify({
                    SelectedValue: selectedValue,
                    KeyValue: KeyValue,
                    DdlCltVal: ddlCltVal,
                    DdlLocVal: ddlCltVal,                    
                    DdlstfVal: ddlstfVal,
                    BtnID:btnid,                    
                    StrDate: strDate,
                    EndDate: endDate,
                    currentPage: currentPage
                });
            $.ajax({
                    contentType:  "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: 'POST',                       url:'http://localhost:8043/Modules/CourierReport/services/CourierReport.asmx/ExportReport',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data:data,
                    success: function(result){
                    alert (result.d);
                    //should i do any thing here?
                    },
                    error: function(error){
                    alert("error");
                    }
                });
                    return false;
```

});

Comment: what is the output of your service? use console.log to check

Comment: @SatyakiChatterjee till  now my web service  stores the excel file on server then return the name of that excel to client it just work file but i want to download that excel to client rather than storing to server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't to know to create and download excel using ajax call but I can recommend you to save excel somewhere in file system of server and download it using `window.location`

Sample code will be (can't modify your code due to time limit but I will be happy to do it later)

jquery:

```
$.ajax({
   contentType:  "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   type: 'POST',                       
   url:'http://localhost:8043/Modules/CourierReport/services/CourierReport.asmx/ExportReport',
   dataType: 'json',
   data:data,
   success: function(result){
                window.location("saved file path with come here");     
            },
   error: function(error){
              alert("error");
          }
});
```

asmx file code:

```
 [WebMethod]
 [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
 public string ExportReport()
 {
    System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gvFiles.RenderControl(htw);
    string renderedGridView = sw.ToString();
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"Path on server to save file", renderedGridView);
 }
```

Comment: i give the saved file path as your suggest but it raise following error TypeError: window.location is not a function
 

window.location("http://localhost:8043/CourierReport/services/userexports/" + cl...

Comment: try window.location.href = path